# How can I backup couchdb data

Tags: docker, couchdb, hyperledger-fabric, docker-swarm

How can I backup CouchDB data, because once we down the hyper ledger fabric network, we lost our previously stored data on CouchDB.
Is there any CouchDB cloud available for storing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [IBM Cloudant](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/cloudant) is a cloud service based on and fully compatible with CouchDB.
IBM also has a [hyperledger-based blockchain offer](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blockchain-platform) so you might be able to combine both for your project.
FUll disclosure: I work for IBM.